# How does this work ls *[^0-9]*

Tags: ls, wildcards

I am learning the wildcards. 
I see that 
`ls *[0-9]*` would list all the files/directories with numbers in its names so shouldn't `ls *[^0-9]*` list all the files/directories without numbers in the middle of its name? I see that some of the files that command listed has numbers.

`file1.txt` and `file1~` were the once that were listed.

Comment: The `*` still match any character, including numbers. Basically the pattern matches any file name including at least one non-numeric character.

Answer (score 3):

`[0-9]` matches any digit, so `*[0-9]*` matches any string that has at least one digit.

`[^0-9]` matches character that isn't a digit, so `*[^0-9]*` matches any string that has at least one non-digit.

`file1.txt` has both digits and non-digits, so it matches both patterns.

---

With regular filename patterns, there's no way to use a single pattern to match a string that does not contain a particular character or characters.

On the other hand, with regular expressions, `^[^0-9]+$` would match strings that are made entirely of non-digits, as would the extended glob `+([^0-9])` in Bash or ksh. (needs `shopt -s extglob` in Bash.)